# why does react do more than one re-render on app initialization

Tags: reactjs

I get that a component re-renders a component when the state changes. Thus, I expect, when my fetch completes and `setState` runs I App.js will re-render and since it contains a child component, that child component will also re-render. But what I don't understand is that my app is doing all of that three times. This is what my console says when I first start the app:

[image: the console upon app initial load]

index.js is just `<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>`

And, yes, I know the installHook lines are because of React Dev Tools, but that doesn't answer why the cycle goes three times instead of 2.

App.js:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CardList from './components/card-list/card-list.component';

class App  extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      nameList: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users' )
      .then(( response ) => response.json()) 
      .then(( users ) => 
        this.setState(() => {
          return { nameList: users }
          // return { monsters: users };
        })
      )
  }

  render () {
    console.log('App.js render', this.state.nameList.length)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CardList cards={ this.state.nameList } />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

components/card-list/card-list.component

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class CardList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { cards } = this.props;
    console.log( 'CardList render', cards.length );
    return (
      <div>
        { cards.map(( card ) => (
          <h1 key={ card.id }>{ card.name }</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CardList;
```

Comment: First render is from mounting. Second render from `<React.StrictMode>`, which simulates unmounting/remounting components in dev builds. Third render is from setting state.

Comment: what to do if I want to not have that behavior while keeping strict mode? For APIs, we can use react query. but for custom component with mount and unmount effects this is super annoyhing! @NicholasTower

Comment: `what to do if I want to not have that behavior while keeping strict mode?` That seems like a contradiction to me. If you don't want this behavior, then what would be the point of keeping strict mode? The goal of strict mode is to force you to confront these situations of mounting, unmounting, etc. That in turn allows you to detect bugs more easily, at which point you can add cleanup logic to your `useEffect`s, thus fixing the bugs.